# know when data chunk transfer is closed

Tags: php, http, transfer

how i can know in my php code when a data transfer is closed by the client ?

i have found this code (bellow) on stackoverflow but i want to write a text into a file when the client close him window...

```
<?php
        header('Content-Encoding', 'chunked');
        header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
        header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        header('Connection', 'keep-alive');

        ob_flush();
        flush();

        $p = "";  //padding
        for ($i=0; $i < 1024; $i++) { 
            $p .= " ";
        };
        echo $p;

        ob_flush();
        flush();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
            echo "string";
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(2);
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling [`connection_aborted()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) you can find out if the client is still connected or not. This could be done within your `for` loop like below.

Also you will need to tell PHP to continue execution after the client disconnects by calling [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php). If you don't do that, your script will terminate as soon as the client disconnects. Depending on your PHP config, you may also need to set a larger or unlimited time limit using [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

```
ignore_user_abort(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {

     if(connection_aborted()){
         // client disconnected, write to file here
     }

     echo "string";
     ob_flush();
     flush();
     sleep(2);
}
```